# Spring MVC command object and redirect attributes

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have a simple scenario:

User submits form, if there are binding errors I redisplay it, otherwise I set a flash attribute and redirect to the home page. I can't get the command object and `RedirectAttributes` to play together though, I can either validate the command object or use redirect attributes but not both. This gives me a 400 Bad Request

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/set", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String setPassword(@AuthenticationPrincipal User currentUser,
                          @Validated @ModelAttribute("command") SetPasswordCommand command,
                          RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes,
                          BindingResult bindingResult) {
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors())
        return SET_PASSWORD_VIEW_PATH;
    ...
    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("flashMessage", "Password changed");
    return "redirect:/";
}
```

This works but without the flash attrbute:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/set", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String setPasswordPost(@AuthenticationPrincipal User currentUser,
                              @Validated @ModelAttribute("command") SetPasswordCommand command,
                              BindingResult bindingResult) {
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors())
        return SET_PASSWORD_VIEW_PATH;
    ...
    return "redirect:/";
}
```

What is the recommended pattern for handling this sort of thing?

Comment: Switch the order. The `BindingResult` must always directly follow the model attribute. (As explained [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-ann-arguments)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method signature is wrong, as explained [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-arguments) the `BindingResult` must directly follow the model attribute.

> `org.springframework.validation.Errors` / `org.springframework.validation.BindingResult` validation results for a preceding command or form object (the immediately preceding method argument).

So moving the `RedirectAttributes` after the `BindingResult` will make it work.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/set", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String setPassword(@AuthenticationPrincipal User currentUser,
                      @Validated @ModelAttribute("command") SetPasswordCommand command,
                      BindingResult bindingResult,
                      RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) { ... }
```